# Different up/down key functions in different modes in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard

I am using following code in my init file :

```
noremap <Up> gk
noremap! <Up> <C-O>gk
noremap <Down> gj
noremap! <Down> <C-O>gj
```

(from: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_by_screen_lines_instead_of_file_lines)

This is to move the cursor one 'displayed line up' and not to one line up when using up key. Similar for down key.

However, now when I go to command mode and press ':' to insert a command, I cannot use up key to get previous command. Is there any way to get previous commands with up and down keys while using above code for insert mode? Thanks for your help.

Edit: The output of `:verbose cmap <Up>` is:

```
 <Up>        * <C-O>gk
```

Comment: What is the result of `verbose cmap <Up>`.

Comment: Added in question  above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Vim configuration file, the lines

```
noremap! <Up> <C-O>gk  
noremap! <Down> <C-O>gj
```

will affect the `Insert mode` and `Command-line mode`. So If you want it to only affect the `Insert mode`, you can chanage it with

```
inoremap <Up> <C-O>gk  
inoremap <Down> <C-O>gj
```

You can check the help with `:help noremap!` to inspect the modes it works.

Comment: What about lines without <C-o>. Are they needed? Do they also need to have inoremap rather than noremap?

Comment: The `<C-o>` is not needed. The function of `<C-o>` is that `execute one command, return to Insert mode`. By default <Up> works in Insert-mode in Vim like any other editors, but it is not up and down by screen lines. So if you want up and down by screen lines, you still need `inoremap`.